# Need help on python displaying information in a certain way

Tags: python-3.x

```
empmangpro = True
employees = []
while empmangpro == True:
    try:
        empcount = len( employees )
        print( "--------------------Employee Management System--------------------" )
        print( "" )
        print( "There are " + str( empcount ) + " employees in the system." )
        print( "" )
        print( "------------------------------------------------------------------" )

        print( "1. Add new employee" )
        print( "2. View all employees" )
        print( "3. Search employee by SSN" )
        print( "4. Edit employee information" )
        programselection = int( input( "Please select your option number: " ) )

        if programselection == 1:
            employee = []
            while True:
                try:
                    print( "-----------------------------------------------------------------" )
                    print( "                    Employee information" )
                    print( "" )
                    print( "-----------------------------------------------------------------" )
                    print( "" )
                    name = input( "Employee First and Last Name: " )
                    ssn = input( "Social Security Number: " )
                    phone = input( "Phone Number: " )
                    email = input( "Email: " )
                    salary = input( "Salary: $" )
                    print( "" )
                    print( "" )
                    print( "---------------------- {0:s} ----------------------------".format( name ) )
                    print( "Social Security #: {0:s}".format( ssn ) )
                    print( "Phone Number: {0:s}".format( phone ) )
                    print( "Email Address: {0:s}".format( email ) )
                    print( "Salary: ${0:s}".format( salary ) )
                    print( "---------------------------------------------------------------" )
                    print( "" )
                    employee.append( name )
                    employee.append( ssn )
                    employee.append( phone )
                    employee.append( email )
                    employee.append( salary )
                    employees.append( employee )
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print( "Please Enter Valid Information." )
                    continue
        elif programselection == 2:
            i = 0
            empstr = ""
            while i < len(employees):
                empstr = empstr + "------------------ " + employees[i][0] + " ------------------------" + "\n"
                empstr = empstr + "SSN: " + employees[i][1] + "\n"
                empstr = empstr + "Phone: " + employees[i][2] + "\n"
                empstr = empstr + "Email: " + employees[i][3] + "\n"
                empstr = empstr + "Salary: $" + employees[i][4] + "\n"
                empstr = empstr + "-----------------------------------------------------" + "\n"
                i += 1
            print(empstr)
            print("\n")
        elif programselection == 3:
            ssnSearch = input("Enter SSN to search by:")
            i = 0
            j = 0
            k = 0
            empstr = ""
            while i < int(empcount):
                while j < 5:
                    if employees[i][j] == ssnSearch:
                        while k < 5:
                            empstr = empstr + employees[i][k]
                            if k != 4:
                                empstr = empstr + ", \n"
                            k += 1
                    j += 1
                j = 0
                i += 1
            print(empstr)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter valid information")
        continue
```

How would I display programselection == 3  to look like programselection == 2?

Comment: create a function that does all this for you. Then call the function by sending in the argument. that way you reduce the code repetition

Comment: I wouldnt know how to do that  I'm only a month in learning python

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function and call it to print the values.

```
def print_empInfo(emp):
    print( "" )
    print( "" )
    print( "---------------------- {0:s} ----------------------------".format( emp[0]) )
    print( "Social Security #: {0:s}".format( emp[1]) )
    print( "Phone Number: {0:s}".format( emp[2] ) )
    print( "Email Address: {0:s}".format( emp[3] ) )
    print( "Salary: ${0:s}".format( emp[4] ) )
    print( "---------------------------------------------------------------" )
    print( "" )

empmangpro = True
employees = []

while empmangpro == True:
    try:
        empcount = len( employees )
        print( "--------------------Employee Management System--------------------" )
        print( "" )
        print( "There are " + str( empcount ) + " employees in the system." )
        print( "" )
        print( "------------------------------------------------------------------" )

        print( "1. Add new employee" )
        print( "2. View all employees" )
        print( "3. Search employee by SSN" )
        print( "4. Edit employee information" )
        programselection = int( input( "Please select your option number: " ) )

        if programselection == 1:
            employee = []
            while True:
                try:
                    print( "-----------------------------------------------------------------" )
                    print( "                    Employee information" )
                    print( "" )
                    print( "-----------------------------------------------------------------" )
                    print( "" )
                    name = input( "Employee First and Last Name: " )
                    ssn = input( "Social Security Number: " )
                    phone = input( "Phone Number: " )
                    email = input( "Email: " )
                    salary = input( "Salary: $" )
                    
                    employee.append( name )
                    employee.append( ssn )
                    employee.append( phone )
                    employee.append( email )
                    employee.append( salary )
                    employees.append( employee )
                    
                    print_empInfo(employee)
                    
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print( "Please Enter Valid Information." )
                    continue
        elif programselection == 2:
            i = 0
            while i < empcount:
                print_empInfo(employees[i]) #pass each employee info to print
                i += 1
        elif programselection == 3:
            ssnSearch = input("Enter SSN to search by:")
            i = 0
            while i < empcount:
                if employees[i][1] == ssnSearch:  #ssn is the 2nd element for each emp. check explicitly
                    print_empInfo(employees[i]) #pass the found employee to print
                    break #once printed, exit the loop
                i += 1
            print ('Employee not found') #if it went thru full loop, emp was not found

    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter valid information")
        continue
```